# Update SQL tables with Windows Form entries

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to be able to update my SQL data tables with entries from Windows Form but I have tried everything and it is not working.
I keep having errors, especially, "failed to convert string to decimal".
I have two tables, one is overall Members tables and the second is the recurrent record table for payment with dates.

The deposit section should add up for each Members and linked to the members table, which I have not been able to achieve too.

```
//NC-4 Create account.
    private void btnCreateAccount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //NC-5 Set up and run stored procedure only if Customer Name is present.
        if (isCustomerName())
        {
            //NC-6 Create the connection.
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);


            //NC-7 Create a SqlCommand, and identify it as a stored procedure.
            SqlCommand cmdNewCustomer = new SqlCommand("dbo.epaNewCustomer", conn);
            cmdNewCustomer.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;



            //NC-8 Add input parameter from the stored procedure and specify what to use as its value.

            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@titheID", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "titheID"));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@titheID"].Value = txtTitheID.Text;
            this.txtMemberID.Text = Convert.ToString(parsedMembersID);

            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@surName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "surName"));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@surName"].Value = txtSurname.Text;

            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "Name"));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@Name"].Value = txtName.Text;

            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@otherName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "otherName"));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@otherName"].Value = txtOthernames.Text;

            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Gender", SqlDbType.NChar, 6, "Gender"));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@Gender"].Value = cmbGender.Text;

            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dob", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8, "dob"));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@dob"].Value = dptDob.Value;

            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Age", SqlDbType.Int, 8, "Age"));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@Age"].Value = txtAge.Value;

            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@phone", SqlDbType.Decimal, 25, "phone"));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@phone"].Value = txtPhone.Text;


            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "email"));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@phone"].Value = txtEmail.Text;

            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@addressHouse", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 1000, "addressHouse"));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@addressHouse"].Value = txtAddress.Text;

            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@stateOrigin", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "stateOrigin"));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@stateOrigin"].Value = txtStateOrigin.Text;

            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@country", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "country"));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@country"].Value = txtCountry.Text;

            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@profession", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50, "profession"));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@profession"].Value = txtProfession.Text;

            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@department", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15, "department"));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@department"].Value = cmbDepartment.Text;

            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Amount", SqlDbType.Money, 8, "Amount"));
            amount = txtDeposit.Value;
            string Amount = String.Format("Amount: {0:C}", amount);
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@Amount"].Value = Amount;


            //NC-9 Add output parameter.


            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@titheID", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@titheID", SqlDbType.NChar, 10, "titheID"));
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@titheID"].Value = this.parsedMembersID;
            cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@titheID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            bool isDecimal = decimal.TryParse(txtPhone.Text.Trim(new[] { '\"' }), out phone);
            if (isDecimal)
                cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@phone"].Value = phone;



            //NC-10 try-catch-finally
            try
            {
                //NC-11 Open the connection.
                conn.Open();

                //NC-12 Run the stored procedure.
                 cmdNewCustomer.ExecuteNonQuery();


                 MessageBox.Show(" Congratulations!. Account" + " for " + txtName.Text + " with TitheID " + txtTitheID.Text + " has been created successfully.");
            }
            catch (SqlException se)
            {
                //NC-14 A simple catch.

                MessageBox.Show("Sorry, Error in Transaction. Account" + " for " + txtName.Text + " with TitheID " + txtTitheID.Text + "  could not be created.");

                MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
            }
            finally
            {


                //NC-15 Close the connection.
                conn.Close();

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: PhoneNumber is a decimal?

Comment: Yes Steve, Phone Number is decimal in the SQL Table

Comment: what is your question? ho to convert to decimal?

Comment: @CPMunich, Not just to conver to decimal, to get appropriate coding to save data from Windows Forms into the DataSet and updating the Sql Database as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but you're assigning phone from text field and also from email field:

```
cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@phone"].Value = txtPhone.Text;
cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@phone"].Value = txtEmail.Text;
```

And then you also have this:

```
cmdNewCustomer.Parameters["@phone"].Value = phone;
```

At least I would try by removing the first 2.

If that doesn't help, use profiler to see what value you're actually sending to the database.

Comment: I have corrected that;  even after I have posted this, just this morning while going through the code again.

Comment: I have fixed it guys.